# Is it possible to tell jdl or jhipster to use Integer as id type?

Tags: jhipster

For now all newly created entities get Long id type. I would like to use Integer instead.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

Would like to have Integer here when I create a new entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible, you must edit generated entities and Liquibase migrations. As this is a trivial change, we don't implement it, see policy #2 in http://www.jhipster.tech/policies/